# SQL count number of occurrences in different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have 4 tables in my db: incoming letters, outgoing letters, local letters and employee. In "letters" tables, there is a register_employee that have register this letter.

Every employee has his/her unique id (for example "3de9a23e-b927-4a27-a66a-c1f30b8c1464").

Tables look like this:

```
employee:
 id         first_name    last_name   age  

incoming:
 id      register_employee  summary     letter   adress   date_sent
```

"Outgoing" and "local" tables look same as "incoming" table.

I need to count how many letters have been registered by each employee and which type.

Example results:

```
employee      incoming  outgoing  local 
Bob Marley      45        33        5
John Travolta   31        10        9
George Bush     98        15        38
```

I tried to use full joins and nested Select statments, but results that I have got are probably wrong cause I am getting millions of count for each employee (I don't have so many letters in db).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OUTER JOIN` and `GROUP BY` as follows:

**-- Updated**

You can use multiple sub-query:

```
select e.id, e.firstname,
       (select count(*) from incoming i where i.register_employee  = e.id) as incoming_letter,
       (select count(*) from outgoing o where o.register_employee  = e.id) as outgoing_letter,
       (select count(*) from local l where l.register_employee  = e.id) as local_letter
  from employee e
```

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesnt work, i am still getting big numbers. Also the numbers are the same for all tables [link](https://imgur.com/a/5TBYYDO)

Comment: show me the exact query used by you alongwith the result

Comment: [with distinct](https://imgur.com/a/SEAp6yP) and [without distinct](https://imgur.com/a/KfRFkJ9)

Comment: I found solution for the problem (i posted an answer) but i will try yours because it seems that my solution have a lot of useless actions. I will try now and tell you if it worked. @Popeye

Answer (score 1):

We count the number of letters under different categories & left join them to the master employee table

```
select employee.first_name , t1.incoming, t2.outgoing, t3.local from (    
    select * from employee 
    left join
    (select register_employee, count(*) as incoming from incoming_letters group by register_employee) t1 on employee.id = t1.register_employee
    left join
    (select register_employee, count(*) as outgoing from outgoing_letters group by register_employee) t2 on  employee.id = t2.register_employee
    left join
    (select register_employee, count(*) as local from local group by register_employee) t3 on employee.id = t3.register_employee ) v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT incom.id,incom.name,incom.incoming,out.outgoings,loc.local
FROM (SELECT 
        employees.id             as id,
        employees.short_name     as name,
        COUNT(incomings.register_employee) as incoming
      FROM employees
      LEFT JOIN incomings ON incomings.register_employee = employees.id)
      GROUP BY employees.id, employees.short_name) as incom
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
             employees.id  as id,
             COUNT(outgoings.register_employee) as outgoings
      FROM employees
      LEFT JOIN outgoings ON outgoings.register_employee = employees.id
      GROUP BY employees.id) as out
ON incom.id=out.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
             employees.id  as id,
             COUNT(local.register_employee) as local
      FROM employees
      LEFT JOIN outgoings ON local.register_employee = employees.id
      GROUP BY employees.id) as loc
ON incom.id=loc.id;
```